# Pom Pom Program Not Resizing

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've created a program, using the HTML5 canvas, which draws a pom pom, with the parameters size, x, y, fluffiness, and color. The pom pom is created by drawing lines coming out from the center, and the parameter fluffiness determines how many strands come out from the center. I have a slider which determines the size of the pom pom, and, when I adjust the slider and submit the size, it should change the size of the pom pom. However, when I make the size smaller, it doesn't get smaller. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<canvas id="a"></canvas>
<div id="control">
  Size:<br>
  <input type="range" id="size" min="50" max="100" value="50">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var b = document.getElementById("a");
var c = b.getContext("2d");
b.width = window.innerWidth;
b.height = window.innerHeight;
function pom_pom(size, x, y, fluffiness, col) {

  c.strokeStyle = col;
     setInterval(function() {
  for(var i = 0; i <= fluffiness; i++) {

    //c.clearRect(0, 0, b.width, b.height);
    c.moveTo(x, y);
    c.lineTo(x + Math.sin(i)*size, y + Math.cos(i)*size);
    c.stroke();

  }
        }, 100);
}
pom_pom(50, b.width/2, b.height/2, 50, "#00ff00");
function check_param() {
  var sizea = document.getElementById("size").value;
  c.clearRect(0, 0, b.width, b.height);
  console.log(sizea);
  pom_pom(sizea, b.width/2, b.height/2, 50, 0, "#00ff00");
}
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function() {
  check_param();
});
document.getElementById("refresh").addEventListener("click", function() {
  c.clearRect(0, 0, b.width, b.height);
});
```

CSS:

```
#a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
#control {
  z-index: 100;
}
input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: auto;
  height: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, purple, blue);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
#col {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

https://codepen.io/Rainy123/pen/qxOGKK?editors=0110

Comment: I wanted to debug it, but your codepen froze my computer.

Comment: I'm so sorry! I forgot to mention that the more you slide the size slider, the laggier the program gets. Adding "?turn_off_js=true" at the end of the URL should fix the problem.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to warn others who might look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you are missing `c.beginPath()` in your code. Without this, `clearRect()` won't work when you try to declare it. Also, you have `setInterval()` declared in your code, which is not necessary and causes the browser to lag. I assume that you were hoping it would fix the problem. I have removed the submit and reset button including other redundancies in this CodePen: https://codepen.io/KidProgram/pen/RQrBNm

Try and remove `c.beginPath()` to see what happens (hint: you won't be able to make it smaller)

Comment: Thank you so much! I used setInterval to slow down the code to see what was happening and why it was messing up.